# Closing ByteArrayOutputStream in an Android application

Tags: java, android, bytearrayoutputstream

In an Android application I'm sending a picture taken from the `Camera Intent` so I need to transform a `Bitmap` to a byte array. To do this I use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as follow:

```
private byte[] getRawImageData(Bitmap source) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] rawImageData = null;
    try {
        source.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, DEFAULT_COMRESSION, baos);
        rawImageData = baos.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        try {
            baos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception here
        }
    }
    return rawImageData;
}
```

Everything works fine and all, the real question is the difference in the documentation of `ByteArrayOutputStream` between the javadoc and the doc from Android.

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close%28%29) reads

> Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect.

the [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close%28%29) reads:

> Closes this stream. This releases system resources used for this stream.

I am closing the stream not matter what but I would like to know which documentation is correct and why they are different.

Comment: the first and second are correct, depends on the outputstrem implementation, closing a baos, does nothing. however it is good practice to always close streams, no matter from where they come

Comment: Are you worried about what happens to the streams underlying byte array, when `close` is called?

Comment: @epoch but the problem is: **why is it required to close this stream when it does nothing at all?**

Comment: @Perception I don't think that what happens to the underlying byte array is the problem since the stream object will be GCed once out of scope.

Comment: @bvidal - so your question is just plain curiosity then? In any case, the first documentation is correct, the `close` operation on a BAOS is a no-op. As has already been stated and you are currently doing, you should close it regardless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` is a memory based stream (managed and populated by user in code), so there is no effect when you call `close()` on it. The only way to clean up its memory foot-print is by revoking all the references to this object. By then, the **Garbage Collector** will kick-in any time soon in future and do its job to clean up such objects.

However, closing a stream is required when you engage resources like files or input/output socket streams (e.g. `OutputStream`, `InputStream`). When you call `close()` on such streams, the JVM safely releases their local-storage/occupied-memory and avoids any OutOfMemory issues.

So in general, it is good (and sometimes vital) to call `close()` on any type of stream when it is no longer required, but more importantly, it is better to know why should we call.

Answer (score 3):

This is the implementation of ByteArrayOutputStrem.close

```
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

API says *Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect*

so it's safe to omit close(), on the other hand it does not harm, JVM skips calls to  empty methods anyway. It may be used to avoid warnings *resource is not closed*.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the stream won't do any harm, but not closing it might.
So it's better to close it.